# Resize a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm trying to resize a div . here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bj3m24ks/31/

Please don't give me links to other tutorials because i tried them all. iTried to do the `$( ".myDIV" ).resizabel({ handles: "all"});`but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tried the fiddle but in your example you have a misspell, try:

```
$( ".myDIV" ).resizabe({ handles: "all"});
```

note **handles** instead of **handels**

Answer (score 0):

Include the jquery-ui css. 
For example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

Or create your own [theme](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/petervanderwal/bj3m24ks/33/)

Ps. Next time, please, very please, provide a **minimal** example. This JSFiddle is full of non-relevant code. And provide your code within the question itself.